# Can't identify this fish caught off NC coast

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

[image]

It was caught approximately 35 miles off the coast of North Carolina. I've been a charter fisherman for more than 25 years and never seen anything like it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you add the size? It's quite difficult to judge from the photo.

Answer (score 9):

i think this is a frogfish. there is multiple types of this fish. i think this is an Ocellated frogfish. frogfishes related to anglerfishes. memorizing animals by classification eventually helps with identification. little google search and using fishbase site about information helps. this sites very helpful about finding fishes.

[fisbase frogfishes](http://www.fishbase.org/identification/specieslist.php?famcode=192&areacode=)

[frogfish site](http://www.frogfish.ch/species-arten/all-frogfish-species.html)

[this link says it can be found on North Carolina](http://www.fishbase.org/summary/3085)

[image: here i think this is your fish]

[image: another one]